# How to get the data from the parent class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please, help me I'm having trouble on getting data from my parent `div` class.
Can someone help me on how can I get the data. Thanks in advance.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="item hasTooltip slick-slide tooltipstered slick-current slick-active slick-center" data-id="579" data-startmonth="December" data-name="Jom X,sk" data-address=" " data-birthdate="December 21, 2016" data-birthplace="Bangladesh" data-mobile="" data-email="" data-year="2016" data-month="12" data-day="20" data-itemcount="38" data-createintake="John B. Doe" data-attorney="Laura V. Conley" data-slick-index="37" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide037" style="width: 136px;">
    <div class="appointment-date">            <span>Dec. Tue</span>
        <label class="day">20</label>
    </div>
    <h1>•</h1>
    <div class="intake-details">
        <a class="remove-text-decoration" href="http://papersllc.com/carecen/client-profile/579" tabindex="0"><i class="user-initials" data-id="579" data-status="15">JX</i></a>
        <span class="name">Jom X,sk</span>
        <span class="sched">11AM Sksk</span>
        <a class="gotoCalendar" tabindex="0">3 more</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
$('.item .intake-details .gotoCalendar').on('click',function(){
    alert($(this).parent('.item').data('name'))
});
```

`.item` class is the parent class in my query above so when I click the `a` tag having `.gotoCalendar` class is I want to get the data form `.item` class.
Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try using the below code

```
$('.item .intake-details .gotoCalendar').on('click',function(){
    alert($(this).closest('.item').data('name'));
});
```

Comment: Yes, `closest` is the best function in this case, this answer should be accepted.

Comment: Thanks I'm new in jquery so i dont know some of the functions of it.

Comment: Please provide an explanation of what this code does; You'll get more upvotes if you explain why to do something.

Answer (score 0):

No need to add multiple parent() function you can use parents() method to get any level of parent object.

$('.item .intake-details .gotoCalendar').on('click',function()
{

```
   alert($(this).parents(".item").data('name'))
```

});

Comment: ahhhh woah that's great Thanks :D

Answer (score -1):

Opps I get it now hahaha i forgot to add another .parent()

```
$('.item .intake-details .gotoCalendar').on('click',function(){
       alert($(this).parents().data('name'))
});
```

Comment: Never use this approach with chaining `parent` calls. Whenever you slightly change the HTML structure then this code can easily break. Use [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/).